# Catching Info with xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml, eclipse, intellij-idea

this is my input :
using python 2.4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
<Status>
   <_IGPS>
        <Lat>03°14'48"N</Lat>
        <Lon>117°35'03"E</Lon>
        <Type>3D</Type>
        <Status>allowed</Status>
        <Time>17/01/25,09:12:02</Time>
   </_IGPS>
```

and im trying to take only the Lat and Log out of this.

this is the code i use :

```
doc = minidom.parse("t.xml")
temp = doc.getElementsByTagName("_IGPS")
if i print this i get => "<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x02C01E68>" 
*** This is the part that i cant figure out to extract the actualy values ***
```

also at somepoint when i try to do the following :

```
print(temp.** at this point the interpeter does not know what is the type of temp**
```

i used this website as reference as what to do :

```
https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-read-xml-file-dom-example/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your example, you could use next code, where you will get  values Lat and Lon.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml = minidom.parse('t.xml')

lat = xml.getElementsByTagName('Lat')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
lon = xml.getElementsByTagName('Lon')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

print(lat) # 03°14'48"N
print(lon) # 117°35'03"E
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark as correct, Thanks.